# SQL Select WHERE row updated

Tags: sql-server, trigger, select, update

```
USE [RF_WORLD]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[lastdeathtrigg]    Script Date: 08/20/2012 10:52:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Mauro Tamm
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[lastdeathtrigg]
   ON  [dbo].[tbl_pvporderview]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (UPDATE(Death))
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @userserial int;
SELECT @userserial ='serial' WHERE UPDATE(Death)
Insert INTO [RF_WORLD].[dbo].[lastdeath]
(serial)
VALUES (@userserial)
END
```

The where part is suspicious, woudl it work like that? essentially i need it to only select the row serial value if it actually updated.

Comment: There are... many... suspicious parts. Can you describe for us the end result you want? It's really unclear what's going on from this code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several problems with your trigger:

1. You are assuming the trigger fires per row, whereas triggers fire per statement. This means you can't just assign a variable because this won't work if the update affects more than one row.
2. Your query to assign a variable doesn't pull from anywhere - you need to reference the `inserted` and/or `deleted` pseudo-tables.
3. Checking `UPDATE()` only tells you that the column was referenced, but it doesn't tell you whether the value has changed.

Here is how I would re-write your trigger:

```sql
-- this assumes Death is not nullable

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[lastdeathtrigg]
   ON  [dbo].[tbl_pvporderview]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (UPDATE(Death))
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT RF_WORLD.dbo.lastdeath(serial)
    SELECT i.serial FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
    ON i.serial = d.serial 
    AND i.Death <> d.Death;
END
GO
```

Comment: yeah i see now, looks like i simply wasn't aware of this option/inner join feature.
Select The i.serial  is a little unclear. If its  just getting defined AS i, how could it select it before it Was defined?

Comment: FROM is parsed before SELECT, WHERE etc. You can reference the alias constructed in FROM in other clauses.